# Setting fields to dirty to trigger validations in Angular JS

Tags: jquery, angularjs, validation

I am trying to get all the fields in a form and set them dirty.

Something like this :

```
 $timeout(function () {

        $('input').each(function(){

             $(this).$dirty=true;

        });
    }, 0);
```

This is not working. I do understand that something like this works just fine:

```
$scope.form.uName.$dirty = true;
```

But when I iterate through all the fields using jquery, something goes wrong.

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Qdk5M/1302/

Appreciate any help. Thank you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a directive with a `link` function that iterates through the form properties. Use a match to avoid any form object property which contains a `$` to get to only the form fields. Set the `$dirty` property of these to `true`:

```
.directive('makeDirty', function(){
    return function(scope, elem, attr) {
        angular.forEach(scope.form, function(val, key){
            if(!key.match(/\$/)) {
                val.$dirty = true;
            }
        });
        scope.form.$setDirty(); // you can make the form itself $dirty if you wish to
    }
});
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hwtJY/)

The advantage of using a directive here is that it will not run the link code until the form is ready; with some minor refactoring, it could also be reused across multiple forms/controllers.

Comment: Thanks so much..this is exactly what I was looking for... one more question. I believe when you setdirty to the form it does not propagate to all the fields of the form.. is that true ?

Comment: Great - I'm glad. Yes, when you use $setDirty, the fields are unaffected. This is why I tacked it on at the end, after the code which sets `$dirty` on the individual fields.

Answer (score 7):

Since AngularJS 1.3.4 you can use *$setDirty()* on fields ([source](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/e8941c0fe5217d2e705bad8253dc0162aff4c709)). For example, for all fields with error and marked required you can do the following:

```
angular.forEach($scope.form.$error.required, function(field) {
    field.$setDirty();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Jquery elements and Angular form controllers are completely different things. Jquery elements does not have a $dirty property, the variables in form directive's controller's have that. You have to use the second script bit you posted.

Comment: Thanks for the insight... that makes total sense!