# $scope.form.$error is undefined in Angular controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to iterate through all fields that are required and blank in an Angular controller (it's triggered by a certain button being pressed).

I've got this sitting in the controller:

```
angular.forEach($scope.form.$error.required, function (field) {
        //Do some things to these fields
    });
```

[From here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27503281/1736597)

The problem is that I get

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'required' of undefined
```

And in Chrome dev tools `$scope.form.$error` is undefined. I've confirmed that $scope.form is populated as expected.

I think I'm missing something simple, but not sure what it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what you are doing with your form, but here is the fiddle. Take a look at it.

```
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
      <form name="form" novalidate class="simple-form" ng-submit="FormSubmit()">Name:
       <input type="text" ng-model="user.name" required />
       <br />E-mail:
       <input type="email" ng-model="user.email" required/>
       <br />
    <input type="submit" ng-click="FormSubmit()" value="Save" />
       </form>
 </div>
```

I think you are missing "Form Name". But anyways this fiddle works flawlessly. You can put the "debugger;" and chek the values in angular.forEach() function;

http://jsfiddle.net/Satbir/ztxwd8vs/

Comment: Thanks this pointed me in the right direction. I actually did have the form named but the code was saving the object itself to $scope.form which was overriding the actual form object. I untangled them and it worked.